# Labs without equipment - virtual chem lab?

Tags: home-experiment

I am an "international online" high school student with very spotty access to chemistry lab materials needed for some chemistry assignments I am being given.  I would like to know if there exists online virtual chemistry labs, appropriate for a high school student, that will interactively/graphically simulate an actual lab experiment.  For example, I'd like to be able to use an online interface to declare which chemicals, in what quantities, I am placing into a specified beaker, and perhaps heated at a certain temperature for X duration.  This hypothetical chemistry simulation tool might show me the color changing of my solution, which I can then use to answer my homework questions.

I googled and found this example [virtual chem lab](https://chemcollective.org/vlabs), but it seems to only offer pre-determined labs that I can't adapt to my specific homework assignments.  I guess I need something more flexible?

Below is a sample real lab-homework question I am currently expected to perform, even though I have no chemicals or equipment:

- Label one of the test tubes Fe2+. Add 4 milliliters of iron(II) sulfate to the test tube.
- Label the other test tube Fe3+. Add 4 milliliters of iron(III) nitrate to the test tube.
- Add 4 milliliters of potassium thiocyanate to each test tube.
- Observe the contents of the test tubes, noting any evidence of a chemical reaction. Record your observations in the table. If there is no evidence of a reaction, write “no reaction.”

Likewise, here is another example homework question:

- Reuse the same test tubes from part A, labeled Fe2+ and Fe3+. Be sure they’re clean.
- Add 4 milliliters of iron(II) sulfate to the test tube labeled Fe2+.
- Add 4 milliliters of iron(III) nitrate to the test tube labeled Fe3+.
- Add 4 milliliters of potassium iodide to each test tube.
- Add 1 milliliter of the prepared starch solution to each test tube.
- Record your observations, noting any evidence of a chemical reaction. If there is no evidence of a reaction, write “no reaction.”

If this hypothetical chem-sim tool doesn't exist, suitable for my needs, is there some other tactic I can use to find answers in the absence of the correct materials?

Comment: How about just reading a textbook?

Comment: Virtual or real lab experiments help you predict the outcome from what you already seen. Textbooks help you to predict event outcomes you have never seen.

Comment: Make yourself a lab journal and describe what you would do and what you learned from your textbooks should come out of the experiments.